# Выполнение действия после завершения нескольких Task

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Есть несколько объектов типа `Task` или `Task<T>`. Необходимо дождаться завершения работы каждого из этих объектов и выполнить действия по завершению. Можно воспользоваться методом `Task.Wait`, например так:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    var t1 = new Task(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    t1.Wait();
    t2.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Tasks completed");
}

private static void DoSomething2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 2");
}

private static void DoSomething1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 1");
}
```

Однако при большом количестве задач это будет выглядеть достаточно громоздко. Какие способы инфраструктура задач .NET предлагает для ожидания выполнения других задач?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существует несколько способов решения предложенной задачи.

Есть статический метод `Task.WaitAll`, который принимает в качестве аргументов массив задач и блокирует вызывающий поток до завершения всех этих задач. Кроме того, есть перегрузки этого метода, принимающие таймаут ожидания (и возвращающие признак, завершились ли задачи в указанное время) и/или токен отмены ожидания. Также есть перегрузка с параметром, принимающим переменное количество аргументов (ключевое слово `params`):

```
public static void Foo()
{
    var t1 = new Task(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
    Console.WriteLine("Tasks completed");
}

private static void DoSomething2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 2");
}

private static void DoSomething1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 1");
}
```

Не надо путать метод `Task.WaitAll` с методом `Task.WaitAny`, ожидающим выполнения любой из переданных задач.

Если есть возможность писать, используя .NET 4.5, то можно воспользоваться ключевыми словами `async/await` для асинхронного ожидания выполнения задач. Метод `Task.WhenAll` создаст задачу, которая завершится, когда завершатся все задачи, переданные ему в качестве аргументов.

Код ниже будет выполняться синхронно, пока выполнение не дойдёт до инструкции `await`. В этот момент управление будет передано коду, вызвавшему метод `Foo`, а ожидание выполнения задач будет происходить в другом потоке. По завершению выполнения задач управление будет возвращено методу `Foo` и он продолжит работу:

```
public static async void Foo()
{
    var t1 = new Task(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
    Console.WriteLine("Tasks completed");
}

private static void DoSomething2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 2");
}

private static void DoSomething1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 1");
}
```

Кроме того, задача, порождаемая методом `Task.WhenAll`, является обычной задачей, а значит её можно синхронно подождать, используя метод `Task.Wait`:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    var t1 = new Task(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Tasks completed");
}

private static void DoSomething2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 2");
}

private static void DoSomething1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 1");
}
```

Ну и наконец, задачу порождённую методом `Task.WhenAll` можно продолжить, используя метод `Task.ContinueWith`. Этод метод запускает задачу, переданную ему в качестве аргумента, после завершения заданной задачи. В задаче-продолжении при это можно обработать результаты и исключения задач, которые изначально необходимо было подождать:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    var t1 = new Task(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    var continuation = Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tasks completed");
        });

    continuation.Wait();
}

private static void DoSomething2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 2");
}

private static void DoSomething1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something 1");
}
```

**P.S.** Отдельное спасибо @NickVolynkin за предложение задать вопрос и самому ответить на него и @PavelMayorov за идею с ожиданием через `Task.WhenAll`.